# Difference between function and subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl

I´m newbie in `perl` and I need to define a subroutine in `perl`, but I don't understand the difference between `subroutine` and `function`.

When should I use any of them and how can I send parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "when should I use any of them"?

Answer (score 7):

In the documentation, "function" refers to list operators (e.g. `chr`, `print`), named unary operators (e.g. `chdir`) and named nullary operators (e.g. `time`). These are sometimes called "builtin functions" to avoid ambiguity (though there are builtin subroutines too, such as `utf8::upgrade`).

In practice, "function" is commonly used to refer to both builtin functions and anything declared with `sub`.

---

Arguments are usually passed to subroutine as follows:

```
foo($x, $y)
```

Operators don't technically have parameters; they have operands. Most operators that qualify as functions resemble subroutines. [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) documents how to use each one.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a real difference. "Subroutine" is just a name for a function that you write, as opposed to one of Perl's builtin functions. It's okay to call them functions too.

Comment: [`perldoc perlglossary`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#subroutine) says "If the subroutine returns a meaningful value, it is also called a function," but this doesn't jive with common usage (or even the rest of the docs; not everything in `perlfunc` returns a value). It seems like function and subroutine are used interchangeably now.

Comment: I think the important part of the question isn't about the definitions, though, but rather "When should I use any of them and how can I send parameters?"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You're right, but that's really a separate question and one that's a) too broad or b) a duplicate.